# Common glossary between multiple documents

Tags: glossaries, texmf

I am wondering if it is possible, and, what are the best practices for keeping a common glossary file in a similar manner to using a common bibliographic database.

For instance, could I put it somewhere in the 'texmf' folder, where it can be picked up by any document that I choose to use it in?

My work, like probably everyones, uses many acronyms, nomenclatures etc, and I am inclined to keeping one single 'common' glossary file so that there is some uniformity between all of my documents, be it presentations, papers, publications and other submissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the `glossaries` package, you can use the command `\loadglsentries{FILENAME}` to load a `.tex` file that contains all your entries. The default position for this `.tex` file is in `texmf > tex > latex` folder.

```
\usepackage{glossaries}
   \loadglsentries{myentries.tex} % myentries.tex is in texmf > tex > latex folder
```